# How to retrieve data from Firebase when data didn't change

Tags: java, android

I'm quite confused with listeners and Firebase. I understand that the only way to retrieve data from Firebase is listeners. I'm using addListenerForSingleValueEvent to retrieve the username value, which it works well only when that value changes or when I execute this code for a second time. Username value shouldn't change at all but I still need to read it often. How do you read from FB when no changes had occurred?

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("forum")
                    .child("level1exercice1").child("post").child("username");
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading it as a snapshot and then storing it as a cookie for future use?

The following code is from Firebase Docs:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
  .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(1)
  .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
    Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
    return;
  } // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
}
```